# How to stretch text field on multiple pages in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

**Scenario**:
I have a jasper report with multiple text fields inside a detail band. Each text field has the properties:

- Position: Float
- Stretch Type: Relative to tallest object
- Print When Detail Overflows: False
- Stretch With Overflow: True

The details band has the property:

- SplitType: Stretch

**Current Result:**
When one of the text fields is taller than the page and extends to a next page, all other text fields stretch to the end of the page.

**Problem:**
I want all text fields to be able to stretch on the next page as well. If I use the property 'Print When Detail Overflows: True' then this causes the text fields to be 'reprinted' with data duplicated. That is not my intention. I want to be able to stretch the text field to more than one page.

Thank you!

Comment: If the content of those fields does not make them stretch on to the next page, why do you want them to stretch anyway? Do they have a bottom border or something that you want to align?

Comment: That is correct - they have borders I want to align

Comment: I have the same problem. When I have a text field that breaks to the next page, adjoining fields with less data do not span the break regardless of how I tell them to stretch, so on the second page there are no "cell" borders (see screenshot linked below). Also, on the first page, the other text fields stretch TOO much and go all the way to the footer, despite there being some padding that should prevent that -- yet the text field that's stretching behaves appropriately (see screenshot).

Any solution?

Link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWBhI.png

Answer (score 2):

I also have same problem and after playing whole day did not figure out anything :-(.
My workaround was to set whole band to **"Prevent"** split type. It is not solution. Only trying to not have text fields 'reprinted' with data duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting to the field's `Stretch Type` to `Relative to Band Height`. If that didn't work, just play with those properties. I believe you can accomplish it by playing with the properties you mentioned.

Comment: I tried, but does not help. I also played with the properties I mentioned, but couldn't find a solution. I was thinking that may be I am missing some property.